# Performance of mathematical calculations on a text file Java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, math

I'm taking in a text file with around 60,000 lines of point coordinates, (I expect to scale up soon) and performing Mahalanobis distance from each point to every other point, and outputting the result as a text file. That means my results will be nearly 3,600,000,000 lines long. My program creates around 60,000 lines every 1 or two seconds.

Am I correct in thinking my code is not able to be multithreaded? Is there a better way to code this algorithm? How do people deal with processes like these?

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Coord {
        public int a,b,c,d,e,f;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/evanlivingston/2a.txt", true)));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/Users/evanlivingston/1.txt"));
        List<Coord> coords = new ArrayList<Coord>();{


            // for each line in the file
            while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] numstrs = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+"); 

                Coord c = new Coord();


                c.a = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[1]);
                c.b = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[2]);
                c.c = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[3]);
                c.d = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[4]);
                c.e = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[5]);
                c.f = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[6]);

                coords.add(c);

            }


// now you have all coords in memory
    int counter = 0;        {
for(int i=0; i<coords.size(); i++ ) 
    for( int j=0; j<coords.size(); j++, counter++ ) 
    {
        Coord c1 = coords.get(i);
        Coord c2 = coords.get(j);
        double foo = ((c1.a - c2.a) * (c1.a - c2.a)) *1 ;
        double goo = ((c1.b - c2.b) * (c1.b - c2.b)) *1 ;
        double hoo = ((c1.c - c2.c) * (c1.c - c2.c)) *2 ;
        double joo = ((c1.d - c2.d) * (c1.d - c2.d)) *2 ;
        double koo = ((c1.e - c2.e) * (c1.e - c2.e)) *4 ;
        double loo = ((c1.f - c2.f) * (c1.f - c2.f)) *4 ;
        double zoo = Math.sqrt(foo + goo + hoo + joo + koo + loo);

        out.println(counter + "; " + i + " " + j + " " + zoo);
       System.out.println(counter + "; " + i + " " + j + " " + zoo);

    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

My input file looks like

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 0 0 1

....

59318 12 2 12 2 12 2
```

The first number is a place holder. It's a list of all combinations with replacement limited to the amounts you see in the last line.

It seems now as though the calculations will take about 16 hours, that still seems too long. Not to mention I estimate the final text output to be around 120 GBs.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you could give us more information about your goal we could help you improve your code.

Comment: I bet 2/3 of the time is spent parsing and formatting numbers. If you can arrange it so that you could read binary integers and write binary floats you would a) save time b) probably save space in the output file c) have an output file you culd random access for a specific result.

Comment: Integer.parseInt is quite lame, you could look for a faster implementation.

Comment: Weezul, I'm attempting to create use a list of all possible configurations of N amount of bodies existing in K amount of dimensions, I'd then like to find the distance between all those possible configurations. The code above is for the last process. Later I'll deal with sorting and managing the data, for now I'd just like to perform the calculations.

Comment: can you post a small sample of the input file for consideration?

Comment: See my updated multi-threaded code below. What is your target performance? Under 1hr? Then get a 4 CPU machine and a very fast disk drive (solid state, for instance).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is **very** inefficient. You re-read the file second time on every line(!!!) in the file. Disk IO is very slow.

What you should do is to load the file into a parsed memory structure (an array of doubles), and then do a nested loop over it.

> Am I correct in thinking my code is
>   not able to be multithreaded?

You're incorrect. This task would benefit a lot from threading. But your first priority is to get rid of repetitive IO. I'd guess the performance would be good enough then.

**UPDATE** to **UPDATE**

Rewrote your class to multiple threads (4 by default). Downside: lines in the output file are not written in order, though by using unix sort utility you may sort it after the computation, if needed. Both A->B and B->A are still calculated as I couldn't come up with a simple way to store the result of A->B short of using Java 64bit and installing some 64G of RAM.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coord {
    public int a, b, c, d, e, f;

    private static class CoordsThread extends Thread {
        private int start;
        private int end;
        private List<Coord> coords;
        private PrintWriter out;

        public CoordsThread(int start, int end, List<Coord> list, PrintWriter out) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.coords = list;
            this.out = out;

            // last block can be shorter
            if( this.end > this.coords.size() ) this.end = this.coords.size();
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("started thread "+getName()+" for ["+start+";"+end+")");
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < coords.size(); j++ ) {
                    Coord c1 = coords.get(i);
                    Coord c2 = coords.get(j);
                    double foo = ((c1.a - c2.a) * (c1.a - c2.a)) * 1;
                    double goo = ((c1.b - c2.b) * (c1.b - c2.b)) * 1;
                    double hoo = ((c1.c - c2.c) * (c1.c - c2.c)) * 2;
                    double joo = ((c1.d - c2.d) * (c1.d - c2.d)) * 2;
                    double koo = ((c1.e - c2.e) * (c1.e - c2.e)) * 4;
                    double loo = ((c1.f - c2.f) * (c1.f - c2.f)) * 4;
                    double zoo = Math.sqrt(foo + goo + hoo + joo + koo + loo);

                    synchronized (out) {
                        out.println(i*coords.size()+j + "; " + i + " " + j + " " + zoo);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("completed thread "+getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("2.txt")));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("1.txt"));
        List<Coord> coords = new ArrayList<Coord>();

        // for each line in the file
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] numstrs = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");

            Coord c = new Coord();

            c.a = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[1]);
            c.b = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[2]);
            c.c = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[3]);
            c.d = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[4]);
            c.e = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[5]);
            c.f = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[6]);

            coords.add(c);
        }

        System.out.println("total lines read: "+coords.size());

        int threadsCount = 4;
        List<Thread> ths = new ArrayList<Thread>();

        int blockSize = coords.size()/threadsCount+1;
        for( int i=0; i<threadsCount; ++i  ) {
            CoordsThread ct = new CoordsThread(i*blockSize, (i+1)*blockSize, coords, out);
            ct.setName("Block"+i);
            ths.add(ct);
        }

        for (Thread th : ths) {
            th.start();
        }

        for (Thread th : ths) {
            th.join();
        }

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: When the whole file residents in memory you can just double for loop over them and output it.

Comment: yamburg, I'm pretty new to arrays, can you perhaps point me in a good for dealing with text files in terms of array, retrieving information stored in array. Either way, your response in insightful, thanks

Comment: Yamburg, are you saying it's possible to save all 60,000 lines of coordinates as elements in an array, then I ought to break one array entry into another array so that I can do my calculations on each element in each line?

Comment: No, I didn't say that. You only need one array, and two indexes pointing to that array. Each index (i and j) represent a line number in the original file.

Comment: Also try replacing `Math.pow(x, 2)` by `x * x`.

Comment: I've updated the code to show my new version, still not happy with it.

Comment: Well, you can cut your time TWICE right away but calculating dist(a,b), but not calculating dist(b,a). The question is where to keep dist(a,b) in a simple way that you could code... hmm...

Answer (score 1):

You are doing lots of repetitive IO, very expensive, more expensive by orders of magnitude than any calculations you are doing.

Also your problem domain fits into a map / reduce scenario very nicely, which is not only easy to multi-thread but you should be able to distribute the calculations over multiple machines as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the file `1.txt` too many times. Read it once, store it in an array of type `int[][]`.

Also, try to increase the size of the `BufferedWriter` instance.

Also, let the `Scanner` instance work on a `BufferedInputstream` with a proper character set.

Comment: his file contains numbers only. charset is a High Magic concept for someone who at learning arrays stage.